# 5.3V power source w/ 24kohm resistor

Tags: gpio, power-supply

Let me start with mention that I don't know shit about electronics. I bought UBEC to power my RPI but it had output voltage of 5.3V so I decided to use 24kohm resistor to lower it down. Now voltage on my meter it's around 5.16V which  I consider safe but RPI won't boot. I'm sure I didn't burun it sice it works from microUSB and when I tried booting it from different UBEC which has acctualy 5V output (I used it in another project).

I'm wondering what might have caused that. Is 24kohm an overkill and taking into consideration resistance of RPi itself it's not enough of power?

Comment: The chances of 5.3V doing any harm to your Pi are pretty remote.  I've powered one from 5.75V for years without causing any noticeable damage.  What did you do with the resistor?  How did you connect it to the Pi and UBEC?

Comment: It's in the middle of 5.3V output of my UBEC and GPIO 5V pin. I just cut the cable and soldered it in between.

Comment: If the resistor is in series it will limit the current flow (ohms law) to 5.3V/24000 ohm = 0.22 milliamps.  The Pi needs around 500 milliamps to boot.  I'd just remove the resistor.

Comment: @joan recommending unsuspecting people to use power supplies out of the specification range is outright dangerous and irresponsible.

Comment: I decided to use the old one since I never finished project I mentioned and today bought another one byth with 5A outoput. I hope so high current won't brake anything.

Comment: A 5A UBEC will be fine.  The Pi will only take as much current as it needs.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious from your post that you have little understanding of electronics (as you apparently admitted - if a little colloquially).

You don't explain exactly how you have connected the supply. This makes a difference.
What is a UBEC?

You are unlikely to damage the Pi with 5.3v, even though this is out of spec, and not to be recommended.

There is absolutely no chance of it working with a 24kΩ resistor in series, but if you are measuring 5.16V then you probably have not done this.

With any electronic circuit, which by definition is non-linear, you cannot control voltage with a series resistor.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot lower voltage with a 24kohm resistor. Please, use a proper 5V 2A+ power supply, unless you want to permanently damage your RPi and/or your current supply and successfully convert them into the puff of magic smoke.

Comment: > You cannot lower voltage with a 24kohm resistor.  

My voltometer says otherwise  

>  Please, use a proper 5V 2A+ power supply  

I would if I could  

> damage your RPi and/or your current supply  

like I said in my post they are both fine